# Rewriting url without a speicifc query parameter using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to rewrite the URL without a specific query string

```
https://example.com?specialVar=xXx1x&para1=xxxx&specialVar=1234&para2=xxxxxx&specialVar=333331&para3=xxxxxx&specialVar=1233z&specialVar=1233z
```

I need about url to be rewritten as

```
https://example.com?para1=xxxx&para2=xxxxxx&para3=xxxxxx
```

I've tried doing this

```
&?specialVar=[\d|a-zA-z]*
```

The result is :

```
https://example.com?&para1=xxxx&para2=xxxxxx&para3=xxxxxx
```

I can't seems to figure out a way to keep only `?` not `?&` both.

Would much appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Simply run a 2nd regex to replace '`?&`' with '`?`'.

Comment: is it possible to do this using one regex expression.

Comment: You can use this: `/specialVar=[\da-zA-Z]*&|&specialVar=[\da-zA-Z]/g`.

Comment: nice! got what i needed. thanks it works 

https://example.com?para1=xxxx234&para2=xxxxxx33331&para3=xxxxxx233z233z

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

`specialVar=[\d|a-zA-z]*&?`

Comment: This would result 

https://example.com?para1=xxxx&para2=xxxxxx&para3=xxxxxx& <= & an sign the end

:(